# How to read a dictionary element from XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to obtain the relevant XML attribute based on the value but I cannot get it to work.

What I am trying to achieve is based on the returned value I want to output the elements name.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's my code so far:

XML:

```
<addresses>
    <address name="house 1">No 1</ipaddress>
    <address name="house 2">Flat 3</ipaddress>
    <address name="house 3">Siccamore Drive</ipaddress>
</addresses>
```

C#:

```cs
string configPath = _AppPath + @"\HouseAddresses.xml";
XDocument addressXdoc = XDocument.Load(configPath);
XElement addressXmlList = addressXdoc.Element("traplistener");
foreach (XNode node in addressXmlLst.Element("addresses").Descendants())
{
    PropertyList = ("string")node.Attribute("name");  
}
```

Comment: what is your output now?

Comment: I think you're going for `node.Attribute("name").Value;`

Comment: Nothing currently, not working, attribute isn't part of XNode it seems.

Comment: Why do you need `XNode`? Just set it to `XElement` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Your XML is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiV, chuck it in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`XNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode(v=vs.110).aspx) type can be seen as a "base". As the documentation states, it `represents the abstract concept of a node (element, comment, document type, processing instruction, or text node) in the XML tree`. Adding a `Attribute` property to a `text`, for example, does not really make sense in the XML context. For that reason, the `XNode` type does not provide a `Attribute` property. The `XElement` type, however, does. Therefore, changing your `foreach` loop to the version bellow, should do the trick:

```
foreach (XElement element in addressXmlLst.Element("addresses").Descendants())
{
    PropertyList = ("string")element.Attribute("name");  
}
```

A "random" note on your code: since `XElement` extends `XNode` the elements returned by `Descendants()` are correctly converted; for this reason, your problem appears to come from the fact that `XNode` does not expose a `Attribute` property, when, in fact, it originates from an unnecessary type conversion.

As an improvement, I would suggest the following:

```
foreach (XElement element in addressXmlLst.Element("addresses").Descendants())
{
    //check if the attribute is really there
    //in order to prevent a "NullPointerException"
    if (element.Attribute("name") != null)
    {
        PropertyList = element.Attribute("name").Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andrei's answer you can also convert the `xml` to a dictionary directly via LINQ:

```
var dictionary = addressXmlLst.Element("addresses").Descendants()
      .ToDictionary(
        element => element.Attribute("name").Value, // the key
        element => element.Value // the value
      );
```

Comment: I like your idea but I don't think it would work. At least not in the current format. `element.Attribute("name").Value` will provide the same `string` for each of the 3 nodes in the example. this will result in duplicate keys and, subsequently in an exception. Switching the key-value would work, but only if the values of the attribute would be unique.

Comment: @AndreiV Eh? No? "house 1" != "house 2" != "house 3"

Comment: Ughh.., yeah, sorry. Got distracted for a moment. Still, as I wrote in my first comment, you must be sure that the attributes will always have unique values.